# CMD.EXE limits windows size to screen size

Tags: windows-7, command-line, multiple-monitors

Is there any way to get a command window larger than the monitor (screen) size. I have multiple monitor, so the desktop size is wider that the monitor, but even after using `MODE CON COLS=300`, CMD.EXE won't let the window size be dragged larger than the monitor size. It adds scroll bars instead!

I suspect the answer is NO!

Comment: I suspect that your suspicion is correct

Comment: ok, what you do is use rdp to connect to netcat on your HP/UX box which connects to rdp on the local host with appropriate resolution to span multiple monitors...

Comment: Did you set the buffer size as well? Windows console apps have *two* dimensions: the window size and the buffer size; the buffer must always be greater than or equal to the window size.

Comment: Yes. Setting both to 300, the window still cannot be made wider than the width of the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Unless things have changed from Windows Vista to Seven, you can right-click on the command window title bar, choose Properties, then Layout tab, and fiddle with the Screen Buffer Size and Window Size settings. I can make the window larger than my monitor screen/desktop that way, and generally make an unusable mess if I try.

Comment: Useful info that I can start CMD.EXE with wider than the standard 80 columns, but unfortunately the limit to monitor width seems to still apply. I'll try fiddling a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative console called [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) can do that but with a max cols of 320 (dialog limit is 200 but `mode 320,X` works).

Turn off "Snap to desktop edges" so it can be positioned across monitors.

[image]